# How to save a vector based map

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, map-saver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using the [laser_line_extraction](https://github.com/kam3k/laser_line_extraction) package to create lines and vector out of the laser points. Is there any way to save these type of maps (line or vector based ) in ROS???? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299022/how-to-save-a-vector-based-map/) by [johnbryant](https://answers.ros.org/users/36731/johnbryant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-07-31**:
How are you storing these maps in your program as they are built? Are they just a list of line segments or do you have additional meta data such as confidence or age?

**Comment by [johnbryant](https://answers.ros.org/users/36731/johnbryant/) on 2018-07-31**:
I only have the following topics that the /line_extractor publishes :

- /line_markers [visualization_msgs/Marker]
- /line_segments [laser_line_extraction/LineSegmentList]
  Is there any way to save these line segments into a yaml or pgm file like you do with the gmapping package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had a look at the laser_line_extraction package and it extracts line segments from a single laser scan message. How are you building a map out of these lines?

There seems to be a step missing. The gmapping package aligns many laser scans with each other to create a single global map. It uses a regular grid to store this map so many scans can be easily added to it.

To make a vector based map you'd have to do the same steps but with line segments which is far more complicated to implement.

To save these maps you would need to use a standard vector format (svg, dxf, etc) or your own custom one. The pgm file format used by gmapping stores raster images so cannot store vector information.

I don't know of any out of the box ROS system that can achieve what you want but it would be a good project to get stuck in and build them.

Hope this makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnbryant](https://answers.ros.org/users/36731/johnbryant/) on 2018-08-01**:
Yes , I got it, I am trying to see how I would make this work, seems hard to implement it but for sure it is worth investigating. Thanks for the answer, it is a bit more clear now.